# Why does my python selenium scraper miss text?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing a simple scraper to extract steam sales info from steamDB (https://steamdb.info/sales/?min_discount=50&min_rating=70). Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://steamdb.info/sales/?min_discount=50&min_rating=70")

# extract the sale table and list of entries
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody")

# key info: name/ price/ discount/ rating/ end time/ appid
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):

    for cnt, td in enumerate(i.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td")):
        print(cnt, td.text)
    print(i.get_attribute("data-appid"))
    print("===========================")
```

Basically I just found the table holds all sales information, and extract the key texts like game name,price, discount, sale starts time, ends time, etc.

However, I found the text for sales ends/ starts/ game release time is missing after several rows of data in the table:

Here is a good one should looks like:

```
0
1 
2 Undertale
Daily Deal 
3 -61%
4 ¥ 14
5 94.18%
6 2 hours # sales end in
7 2 days ago # sales start from
8 4 years ago # game released
391540 # appid
===========================
```

Here is a bad one looks like:

```
0 
1 
2 South Park™: The Stick of Truth™
Ubisoft Publisher Weekend new highest discount
3 -80%
4 $5.99
5 95.53%
6 
7 
8 
213670
```

As you can see, the scraper could detect the `td` tag in index 6,7,8, but it could not extract any text from it.

Some observations:

1. I have checked the dom and I didnt see any difference between the
   row of good one and bad one
2. The issue only reproduces after about the first 10 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because those columns information is loading dynamically when scroll. Please use the below script which will take care of this issue.

```
driver.get("https://steamdb.info/sales/?min_discount=50&min_rating=70")

# extract the sale table and list of entries
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody")

# key info: name/ price/ discount/ rating/ end time/ appid
for i in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='paginate_button next']").location_once_scrolled_into_view
    for cnt, td in enumerate(i.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td")):
        print(cnt, td.text)
    print(i.get_attribute("data-appid"))
    print("===========================")
```

Answer (score 0):

As supputuri said the problem comes from webpage's dynamic loading. After some experiment I found a good solution is to manually simulate the process of scroll down the page, so the code looks something like this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(0.5)
```

The script would scroll down to half of the page, then wait half a second to let webpage load the content, then go through. This depends on the length of the webpage (if the length is too long there would be some "gap" between each scroll)

I know this solution is naive so please tell me if there is any better one.